# Mirrorless Camera / Camcorder fully controlled from PC

Tags: camera, video-camera

I've been reading a lot of recommendations and how-to guides on using Mirrorless/DSLR/Camcorders as a video source with some HDMI capture card, but none seem to indicate (what should be obvious) that the camera controls, including power on/off is still manual on the camera itself, which lead me to wonder if there is any protocol / api for remote control of high end cameras (like what we see in GoPro for example)

and thus the question is two parts:

- is there such a standard protocol?
- what high end cameras out there allow for remote control (including power on / off)?

knowing the answer to the first question, would at least assist in doing better search for devices that support it.

Comment: Many of the professional cameras have a USB, WiFi, or Bluetooth connection that allows for the camera to be controlled by that brand's specific software. You would use that in conjunction with the HDMI capture; But that software may also support capture over the same connection (but lower bandwidth than HDMI). What brand of camera are you interesting in using?

Comment: No HDMI required. All but the most entry-level DSLRs have been capable of connection over USB for a long time; fully-controllable to pretty much any 'soft' control on the camera itself - eg exposure, aperture, focus, WB… but not zoom, as that still requires you to twist the collar, same as if the camera was in your hand. Most of the majors now have additional 'webcam' software [Nikon are last to the game with that, though 3rd party alternatives are already available.]